# Creating encrypted disk images on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

In Mac OS X it is fairly easy to create an encrypted disk image but i was wondering if there was anything equivalent on Windows 7?

I basically want to be able to create a password protected encrypted disk image so that I can store sensitive data safely.

Does anyone have any suggestions for something that works like the Mac OS X encrypted disk image facility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The usual choice is [Truecrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/).

Note that full-disk encryption is still the best way to protect your system.  A disk image will protect the data that you store on it -- but still leaves your swap file, history, and other temporary bits of data vulnerable.